# Syllable count of environmental

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

I seems to me the sound at the end is /tl/ or as far as I and most people I know pronounce it. This applies for most other *-tal* ending words. I know it could be /təl/ but the vowel is not present at all in my pronunciation.

This leads me to ask, is it therefore correct to say environmental is 4 syllables by the definition that a syllable is based on there being a vowel sound for it to be a syllable?

Or do we relax the syllable definition to include the /tl/ sound even though there is no vowel sound present?

Comment: Look here: http://ingles-americano.blogspot.com/2012/06/syllabic-consonants-l-and-n.html  and, of course, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant

Comment: "... do we relax the syllable definition ..." -- how do you define a syllable?

Answer (score 2):

Many languages, including English, have what is known as ***syllabic consonants***. These are sounds that we usually think of as consonants which can serve as the syllabic nucleus.

Usually these are sonorants:

- acre
- little
- kitten, button
- rhythm

But sometimes in words representing onomatopoeia they can be sibilants:

- shhh!
- psst!
- bzzz!

Yours is an example of an L forming the syllabic nucleus, just as it does in *little*.

By the way, the OED has this citation under *liquid*:

> - 1888   H. Sweet *Hist. Eng. Sounds* (new ed.) §21  
>    But those ‘vowellike’ or ‘liquid’ voiced consonants which are unaccompanied by buzz are often also syllabic.

Comment: That particular OED page (2nd edition) can be found [here](http://www.oed.com/oed2/00133952) for free. And the source it cites can be found free [here](https://archive.org/stream/historyofenglish00sweeuoft#page/8/search/consonants+which+are+unaccompanied+by+buzz+are+often+also+syllabic)